# ng-show is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Below is my table markup

```
<tr ng-show="paginate({{$index+1}})" ng-repeat="x in ProductInfo_Pager | orderBy :sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchText | limitTo : rowPerPage" ng-class="$even?'table-danger':'table-info'">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Product}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Location}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Qty}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.UnitPrice | currency : '&#x20B9;':2}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and pager below it

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item" ng-repeat="x in getNumber(rowPerPage) track by $index">
                <a class="page-link" ng-click="pagerIndex=$index+1">{{$index+1}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And AngularJs Code

```
    $scope.ProductInfo_Pager = $scope.ProductInfo;

        $scope.sortType = 'Product'; // set the default sort type
        $scope.sortReverse = false; // set the default sort order
        $scope.searchText = ''; // set the default search/filter term  , 


        $scope.totalItems = $scope.ProductInfo.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.rowPerPage = 5;
        $scope.pagerIndex = 1;

        $scope.getNumber = function (num) {

            var pages = $window.Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / num);
            return new Array(pages);
        }

        $scope.paginate = function (rowindex) {
            var begin, end, index, flag ;
            index = $scope.pagerIndex;
            end = (index * $scope.rowPerPage) - 1; // -1 to sync it with zero based index
            begin = end - $scope.rowPerPage + 1;
            if(rowindex >=begin && rowindex <= end ){
                flag=true;
            }
            else{
                flag=false;
            }
            var d = 0;
            return flag;
        };
```

paginate function() return true or false based on logic which is used in `ng-show` in tr tag with `ng-repeat`, but its not doing show , hide functionality as expected

Logic is : 
Suppose `rowPerPage` is 5 - [5 row can be show up in table at a time]

And we click on 4 in pager so it should show row from 16-20 .

In ng-show paginate function is bind which take row index as parameter , this function check if rowindex falls in between 16 - 20 , if yes than it return true (`ng-show=true`) else false and accordingly should hide that row.

As per mu understanding its two way binding so any change in ng-show should work perfectly but it does not show any effect 
Can someone help me why this is happening

I am a newbie in angularjs

Thanks.

Comment: You don not pass {{}} in ng-show .  It was a good question though ! upvote !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ! ng-show  is not working here and the function is not getting called at all written in ng-show !

If i correctly understand you want to create a pagination :

So i am giving you a very simple  solution of  pagination using a pagination filter .

you need to add this filter  to your app  :

```
app.filter('pagination', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    if (input != undefined && Object.keys(input).length > 0) {
        return input.slice(start);
    }

}
```

});

In your html :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in ProductInfo_Pager | pagination: currentPage * rowPerPage | limitTo: rowPerPage|orderBy :sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchText" ng-class="$even?'table-danger':'table-info'">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Product}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Location}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Qty}}</td>
                <td>{{x.UnitPrice | currency : '&#x20B9;':2}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

In your pagination ul below your table :

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="page-item" ng-repeat="x in getNumber(rowPerPage) track by 
$index">
    <a class="page-link" ng-click="pagerIndex=$index+1">{{$index+1}}
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

in your controller :

```
$scope.numberOfPages = function() {
            if ($scope.ProductInfo_Pager != undefined) {
                return Math.ceil($scope.ProductInfo_Pager.length / 
                  $scope.rowPerPage);
            }

        };
```

Hope it work ! if any doubt please let me know .